# How to show Admob house ads without billing information

Tags: ios, admob, ads, google-ads-api, adsense

I have submitted a game to the Appstore and wanted to promote it through another app I already had submitted before. So I set up a house ad campaign, but no ads are shown in the other app.

I read that I had to set up my billing information, but in Google Ads it is not possible to set up a billing information as an individual, only when running a business. 
And as I have not reached the paying threshold yet, I cannot add my billing info into my Google Adsense account.

Is there anything I could do to successfully show house ads?

Best regards
MB